# Android periodic ble scan

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, alarmmanager, android-ble

I have a BLE thermometer that advertises current temperature exactly every 5 seconds.

I want to write an app (service) for my Android 9 phone (Xiaomi), that will perform periodic BLE scan to read the temperature at least every 2 minutes even when the phone is in sleep mode (screen off) - there will be alarms based on the temperature and they must fire with max. 2 minutes delay from the time the temperature reaches a target.

I read about JobScheduler, AlarmManager, etc. but it looks like that when Android device is in sleep mode, it can fire events very irregularly and that means my 2 minute deadline will not be met.

Can you please advise any solution for this or should I just forget this as Android device is not suitable?

Comment: You will probably have to run a foreground service the whole time, good luck with the Xiaomi phone though.

Comment: Yes, I know I have to run foreground service. But how to schedule my 2 min ble scans so there is no missing ble scan even when the phone is in sleep mode? At the same time, I want to maximize battery life of course.

Comment: If I remember correctly JobScheduler has a 15mins frame, so it's out. AlarmManager is a good candidate, probably with the Idle methods, but some manufacturers won't allow them to run while idle or doze. What I am suggesting is to open the app, start foreground service, handle your own logic of scanning every two minutes. (see: https://dontkillmyapp.com/)

Comment: How should that "logic" look like? For first time, I tried Handler.postDelayed or Timer.schedule and these are out of the game of course. After several hours my phone is idle the ble scan initiates only e.g. once per hour. I also tried to disable all kind of battery optimization stuff for my app in MIUI (I have MIUI 11 on Android 9 and the settings look different from dontkillmyapp.com)